# Return retorna só o primeiro valor da lista (python)

Tags: python

estou criando um bot no discord que exibe os filmes disponíveis no cinema. Ocorre que eu já tinha um Web Crawler em Python que fazia isso, e decidi colocá-lo para funcionar no bot, ao executar um comando. No entanto, ao executá-lo pelo bot ele só retornava o primeiro valor da lista de filmes, então coloquei o return fora do for pensando que resolveria, mas agora ele retorna só o segundo filme, ao invés de retornar todos (gostaria de exibir todos os filmes disponíveis pelo bot).
Como faço para retornar todos os valores de "t1" ?

```
# bot.py
import os
import random
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('token')
GUILD = os.getenv('Teste BOT')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

print(
    f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
    f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n'
)

members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

def filmes():
    my_url = 'https://iguatemi.com.br/saocarlos/cinema/'
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    for title in page_soup.select('li.node-readmore > a'):
        t1 = title.get('title')
    return t1


if message.content == 'filmes!':
    response = filmes()
    await message.channel.send(response)


client.run('Token')
```

Comment: `t1 = title.get('title')` - você está "sobrescrevendo" o valor de `t1` no loop. Se a ideia é retornar uma lista de itens, você deve fazer o `append` com todos os valores obtidos em `title.get('title')`.

Comment: Postei uma solução, porem ainda estava editando alguns erros de digitação, porém agora esta certo, de uma conferida agora e se tiver alguma duvida só dizer, e o caso de usar o embed é bem legal, você ira curtir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

há muitas coisas que te aconselho mudar em seu código, vamos ao primeiro problema seu.

```
    for title in page_soup.select('li.node-readmore > a'):
        t1 = title.get('title')
    return t1
```

desse jeito você só retornará um resultado, como concertar? você pode transformar em um objeto Generator ou criar uma lista e fazer voltar já como uma string formatada, colocarei uma resolução a baixo

```
    titulos = []
    for title in page_soup.select('li.node-readmore > a'):
        titulos.append(title.get('title'))
    return '\n'.join(titulos)
```

agora uma coisa que aconselho mudar em sua estrutura

> o discord.py utilizar os métodos assíncronos, aconselho repensar na sua estrutura para que sempre utilize eles pois você pode parar todos os processos de seu funcionamento por conta de uma função mais demorada tirando toda a vantagem

outra coisa que te aconselho na hora de manda a lista dos títulos do filmes é usar o Embed, você pode pegar instruções por [aqui](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed), é bem fácil de usar.

---

### Edit

se quiser pode tentar criar um generator e caso prefira mandar um titulo por vez

```
def filmes():
    my_url = 'https://iguatemi.com.br/saocarlos/cinema/'
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


    for title in page_soup.select('li.node-readmore > a'):
        yield title.get('title')

if message.content == 'filmes!':
    for response in filmes():
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

---

### edit 2

um exemplo de como ficaria se usasse o Embed.

```
def filmes():
    my_url = 'https://iguatemi.com.br/saocarlos/cinema/'
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


    msg = discord.Embed(title=f'{" Lista de Filmes ":-^30}', colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue())
    for title in page_soup.select('li.node-readmore > a'):
        msg.add_field(name='Filme', value=title.get('title'), inline=False)
    return msg

if message.content == 'filmes!':
    msg = filmes()
    await message.channel.send(embed=msg)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado ! consegui utilizar as soluções do edit 1 e 2, bem completa a resposta e ajudou bastante !

Comment: sempre há um jeito diferente de se fazer, só cabe escolher o melhor  na sua percepção, passei 3 alternativas e espero que ajude bastante e se foi útil não se esqueça de marca as postagens como aceitas.